# With Flutter blocs, how do I use two events with the same callback?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I'm using the library `flutter_bloc` and I have two different events -- one that will accept arguments while the other will not.

```dart
class LoginSubmitted extends LoginEvent {
  const LoginSubmitted();
}

class LoginFromSignup extends LoginEvent {
  const LoginFromSignup({
    this.username,
    this.password,
  });

  final String username;
  final String password;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [username, password];
}
```

However, these two events will pretty much do the same thing. I am having trouble implementing that in my `login_bloc`. Ideally I want something like this:

```dart
    on<LoginUsernameChanged>(_onUsernameChanged);
    on<LoginPasswordChanged>(_onPasswordChanged);
    on<LoginSubmitted>(_onSubmitted);
    on<LoginFromSignup>(_onSubmitted); <-- this doesn't work
```

As you can see above, the line `on<LoginFromSignup>(_onSubmitted);` gives me an error:

```
The argument type 'void Function(LoginSubmitted, Emitter<LoginState>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<void> Function(LoginFromSignup, Emitter<LoginState>)'.
```

I assume my method definition is off:

```dart
void _onSubmitted(
    LoginSubmitted event, <--- this might be problematic
    Emitter<LoginState> emit,
  ) async {
```

With the example above, the `event` arg is accepting `LoginSubmitted`. How do I make it so it accepts both `LoginSubmitted` and `LoginFromSignup`?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `LoginFromSignup` is not a subtype of `LoginSubmitted`.

You can change the `_onSubmitted` function to accept a `LoginEvent`, the class that both (`LoginFromSignup` and `LoginSubmitted`) extend and are subtypes of.

Like this:

```
void _onSubmitted(LoginEvent event, Emitter<LoginState> emit)
```